# Как заставить этот скрипт js правильно срабатывать?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Проект](http://www.bot.immo/) который уже просто замучил меня, правки все время растут как грибы после дождя. На сей раз заказчику понадобилось что бы выбранные значения, передавались на следующую страницу в заглавии меню. Вот как это выглядит сейчас:

[image: Заполняем форму]

кликнем Zoeken и переходим на следующую страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

выбранные значения в форме сохраняются, в строке браузера передаются, но не отображаются в заголовках меню (как на первом скрине). Что необходимо в js дописать что бы критерии поиска отобразились в названии кнопок формы. Есть идея что-то вроде вот такой записи:

```
$(function () {
    $('#searchForm .select [data-bind="label"]').text($("#id_input_for_label").val());
});
```

но данный скрипт во-первых касательно только кнопки Type, а во-вторых он просто убрал из пункта меню название, ничего не передав на следующую страницу.

Код js (касательно кнопки Prijs):

```
    $('.bootstrap-select > .dropdown-menu').on('click', function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

    $('.dropdown-menu .combobox').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
    $toggler = $this.find('[data-toggle="dropdown"]'),
    $comboOptions = $this.find('.combo-options'),
    $valueBlock = $this.find('input[type="text"]'),
    $spanID = $valueBlock.data('label');
    $parentDropdownMenu = $this.closest('.dropdown-menu');

function close() {
    $comboOptions.removeClass('open');
    $parentDropdownMenu.off('click', close); 
}

function toggle(e) {
    if ($comboOptions.hasClass('open')) {
        close();
    } else {
        $comboOptions.addClass('open');
        $parentDropdownMenu.on('click', close);
    }

    e.stopPropagation();
}

$comboOptions.on('click', '.dropdown-menu a', function (e) {
    $('#emptyLabel').hide();
    $('#chLabel').show();
    $('#'+$spanID).text( this.dataset.value||'...' );
    $valueBlock.val(this.dataset.value);
    close();
});

$toggler.on('click', toggle);
```

});

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/martynuk/v2nvgd80/

Comment: А почему бы тебе просто куки не использовать? На одной странице поместил в куки из js, на другой - забрал из php (или даже того же js)

Comment: интересная идея, но как ее реализовать?

Comment: отписал подробнее ниже

Comment: А что мешает взять данные с форм? Ну, или прописать их в меню там где они прописываются в формы? В джаваскрипте возиться с куками и гет параметрами, немного сложно, имхо.

Comment: Если движок просит вас привести код в вопросе, а не кидать ссылку на простыню кода на JSFiddle, то так и надо делать, а не оформлять ссылку как код.

Answer (score 3):

[Простой разбор URL с помощью изоморфного Javascript](http://habrahabr.ru/post/252533/) - парси url и вставляй Value

Comment: + совет при submit проверяй на пустоту значения и не строй url с пустым значением это огромный минус _min_bedrooms=&max_bedrooms=_

Answer (score 3):

Простая функция получения данных из адресной строки

```
<a href="?min_bedrooms=1&max_bedrooms=2" title="Меню">Муню</a>

<script>
    function getGet(name) {
        var s = window.location.search;
        s = s.match(new RegExp(name + '=([^&=]+)'));
        return s ? s[1] : false;
    }

    if(getGet('min_bedrooms'))
    {
      alert(getGet('min_bedrooms') + " + " + getGet('max_bedrooms'));
    }

</script>
```

Если не подходит вбей в яндексе **Получить get параметры с url js**

Comment: не совсем понял как это подходит?

Comment: Извини немножко не так понял, тебе надо получить данные из адресной строки на js

Comment: ну и так можно, но правильней, мы их на первом слайде выбираем, они js записываются в title и когда жмешь выбрать, то осуществляется переход, на выбранные значения, так вот они должны в title сохраниться, что бы видеть по чем происходит выборка... ну как-то так. Одним словом, в Prijs выбрали мин и макс значения, нажали отправить, данные сохранились и на следующей странице вместо Prijs будет мин/макс значения (как на первой форме)

Comment: Функцию я заменил проверил все работает getGet('min_bedrooms'); можешь вставлять так, или присвоить переменой var min_bedrooms = getGet('min_bedrooms'); Если мой ответ был полезен поставь галочку.

Comment: а не с адресной строки, а просто с формы? что бы выбранные значения не стирались. И отображались в пунктах формы.

Comment: Я смотрел на твой поект там ничего не стирается. У тебя есть два варианта извлекать данные из адресной строки, или записывать данные з формы в куки ( cookie ) а потом с кук вытаскивать в форму.

Comment: а просто данные с формы записать в название пунктов?

Comment: Так никто не делает, например я такого не слышал.

Comment: Ну или я тогда чего-то не понимаю, или вы меня. Мы поместили значения при выборке в заглавие пункта меню, что мешает нам при клике поиска сохранить эти данные (не куки, не урлы), а просто значения в том же заглавии. Не касаясь адресной строки.

Comment: У тебя форма передает данные через get запрос , значит они находятся в адресной строке браузера, в текстовых полях как видно они есть, это значит что какая-то функция из адресной строки в текстовые поля вставляет данные, той самой функцией ты можешь вывести данные в заголовок меню. Html + Js <div id="zah"></div> $("#zah").text("Garage");

Comment: а скриптом onready value из inputa в label записать разве нельзя?

Answer (score 0):

Вот 2 ф-ции для обработке coockie на js, нарытые мною когда-то на просторах интернета

```
function setcookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) { 
    // +   original by: Jonas Raoni Soares Silva (http://www.jsfromhell.com) 
    /*
    setcookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure)
    name - название cookie
    value - значение cookie (строка)
    options - Объект с дополнительными свойствами для установки cookie:
        expires - Время истечения cookie. Интерпретируется по-разному, в зависимости от типа:
                    Число — количество секунд до истечения. Например, expires: 3600 — кука на час.
                    Объект типа Date — дата истечения.
                    Если expires в прошлом, то cookie будет удалено.
                    Если expires отсутствует или 0, то cookie будет установлено как сессионное и исчезнет при закрытии браузера.
        path - Путь для cookie.
        domain - Домен для cookie.
        secure - Если true, то пересылать cookie только по защищенному соединению.
        */
    expires instanceof Date ? expires = expires.toGMTString() : typeof(expires) == 'number' && (expires = (new Date(+(new Date) + expires * 1e3)).toGMTString());
    var r = [name + "=" + escape(value)], s, i;
    for(i in s = {expires: expires, path: path, domain: domain}){
        s[i] && r.push(i + "=" + s[i]);
    }
    return secure && r.push("secure"), document.cookie = r.join(";"), true;
} 

setCookie = setcookie;//псевдоним

function getCookie(name) {
    /*myVar = GetCookie("postIDs");*/
    var cookie = " " + document.cookie;
    var search = " " + name + "=";
    var setStr = null;
    var offset = 0;
    var end = 0;
    if (cookie.length > 0) {
        offset = cookie.indexOf(search);
        if (offset != -1) {
            offset += search.length;
            end = cookie.indexOf(";", offset)
            if (end == -1) {
                end = cookie.length;
            }
            setStr = unescape(cookie.substring(offset, end));
        }
    }
    return(setStr);
}
```

Соотв. в js при выборе `setcookie("title_val", "блаблабла", 0, "/");`

На конечной странице в php

```
echo '<title> Заголовок '.$_COOKIE["title_val"].'</title>';
```

Либо через js как-то так

```
 $title = document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
 $title.text = $title.text + ' ' + getCookie("title_val");
```

Comment: это точно то что мне нужно? все как то замысловато:))) я же куки не прошу прописать,  а значения пунктов меню

Comment: Возможно, не совсем верно тебя понял)